# Integrate third party app with Salesforce ensuring a seamless experience

Tags: integration, oauth2, mobile, single-sign-on, saml

I wrapping up a proposal for a client and I'm facing some integration architectural issues. I really need your help!

The client has a self-care website and three mobile apps (android, Windows Mobile, ios) and he's going to get a Salesforce CRM with customer community licenses.

I must satisfy the following requirements:

- User already registered and every new registered users on any of the
  above channels (existing web and mobile apps) must become customer
  portal users
- Guarantee a seamless experience without using customer community ui
  on existing channels
- In an SSO scenario I'm supposing that Salesforce will be the IdP for all client's systems. The reason is that they don't have any IAM and use a simple db table to manage registered users.

Since the app or website is able to authenticate user both as customer community and app/web user it can call web service exposed by Salesforce (logged as customer user) and let the customer access their cases, profile information and log a new support request. Is that right?

What is the best integration architecture/solution in order to meet the above requirements?

I read a lot of resource ([link](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Single_Sign-On_for_Desktop_and_Mobile_Applications_using_SAML_and_OAuth)) on the web but I wasn't able to find the right solution.

Thanks a lot

Piero

Comment: I think this question is too broad.

Comment: Not really, this is a fairly well defined architectural question and the assumptions made show that the person has done significant home work before posting it. The only confusing part is where it says (Android, Apple, iOS) - Apple and iOS are pretty much the same.

Comment: A LOT of home work :). The part where I wrote "..Apple, iOS" is an error I meant  Android, Windows Mobile and iOs).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following assumptions made by you are correct and are also validated by the [link](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Single_Sign-On_for_Desktop_and_Mobile_Applications_using_SAML_and_OAuth) you quoted.

> In an SSO scenario I'm supposing that the Salesforce will be the IdP
>   for all client's systems. The reason is that they don't have any IAM
>   and use a simple db table to manage registered users.

Yes, you would use Salesforce as the IdP in this case. I would strongly encourage you watch [this detailed video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W3okdu8nJHY) to understand how the SSO flow will work in this case. [This](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/976/federated-authentication-for-mobile-crm-products) is another thread which might be helpful.

> Since the app or website is able to authenticate user both as customer
>   community and app/web user it can call web service exposed by
>   Salesforce (logged as customer user) and let the customer access their
>   cases, profile information and log a new support request. Is that
>   right?

I presume the support request here is a custom object that you maintain at your end and want the users to be able to access it via the app. In this case, your mobile apps will be using the [Salesforce Mobile SDK](https://developer.salesforce.com/mobile/services/mobile-sdk) (iOS and Android). The SDK offers REST API wrappers so you can do CRUD operations on standard and custom objects in Salesforce.

> The client has a self-care website and three mobile apps (android,
>   apple, ios) and he's going to get a Salesforce CRM with customer
>   community licenses.

The access to community users for these mobile apps would be managed by the built-in auth mechanism in the Mobile SDK. You need to configure your SSO settings correctly and Mobile SDK would delegate the auth flow accordingly.

***Added to answer below based on additional questions in comments***

> During my weekend home work I learnt that SAML Assertion Flow insn't
>   supported for Community authentication. Is this a problem in the
>   scenario you described before? In particular with the use of mobile
>   SDK.

This is not true. [This](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_communities_implementation.meta/salesforce_communities_implementation/networks_auth_configure_saml.htm) link describes what’s required for community SAML assertion. You do not need to set `organisation_id, portal_id and siteUrl` in case of community but it very much supports SAML.

Comment: @pierus - If this is the info you were looking for, please accept it as an answer so it benefit others.

Comment: When I talk about support request I mean case.

I have some other questions:
- In my particular scenario, is SAML the right choiche?
- During my weekend home work I learnt that SAML Assertion Flow insn't supported for Community authentication. Is this a problem in the scenario you described before? In particular with the use of mobile SDK.

Thank you
Piero

Comment: @Gurav, in order to mark your answer I need to solve some other doubts that prevent me to complete the architecture.

Comment: @pierus - I've updated my answer based on your additional questions. Thanks!

Comment: @Gurav, thank you very much. If I've another question strictly related to the above topic should I create another thread?

I write down question here:
- How the above scenario change if I've an EBS (Tibco) between CRM and other corporate Systems?

Comment: Please post another question and try to provide as much detail as possible. Thanks!